# Do we have an implementation of Bayesian structural time series in Python?

Tags: python, time, time-series, bayesian, bayesian-deep-learning

We are looking for a close pythonian implementation of the r library bsts.
To be precise, I'm looking for something that allows me to emulate the functionality of *'add_regressor'* from *fbprophet*.

1. Have already tried Pybsts (the kernel kept dying), and
2. According to a thread on ***tensorflow_probability*** Github account, it doesn't support multivariate mode yet.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

I recently wrote a version of R's bsts package in Python. It doesn't have all of bsts's features, but it does have options for level, trend, seasonality, and regression. The syntax closely follows statsmodels' UnobservedComponents module. You can find the code and description of the package here: https://github.com/devindg/pybuc.

Comment: just dug into this package that Devin has made. It's super easy to use and understand the workflow. Def recommend trying this out. Great stuff @DevinGarcia

Answer (score 0):

This [blog post](https://blog.tensorflow.org/2019/03/structural-time-series-modeling-in.html) from Tensorflow Probability shows how to add an exogenous regressor with the TFP structural time series tools. In particular, check out the usage of the `temperature_effect` variable in the **Example: Forecasting Demand for Electricity** section!

Comment: [This](https://github.com/tensorflow/probability/blob/main/tensorflow_probability/examples/jupyter_notebooks/Structural_Time_Series_Modeling_Case_Studies_Atmospheric_CO2_and_Electricity_Demand.ipynb) is from the Tensor Flow docs and is the same blog post with a little more explanation